# Iterating over list with Type as Key

Tags: c#, inheritance, ienumerable, typeof

So, I created a list:

```
protected Dictionary<Type, List<Entity>> entities;
```

The Entities shown above inherit multiple interfaces such as Clickable, Hoverable and Focusable.

My question is iterating over them, I need a method that allows quick rendering of the entire list i.e:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Type, List<Entity>> entry in entities)
{
    foreach (Entity e in entry.Value)
    {
        e.Render(delta, drawingContext);
    }
}
```

and also allows for iterating over the individual inherited types:

```
 foreach (Clickable c in entities[typeof(Clickable)])
 {
     ... Perform click
 }
```

For my question: 
does "typeof" include the types that are inherting clickable? e.g:

```
 abstract class ClickableEntity : Entity, Clickable
```

My issue is efficiency and expandability, I understand that I could just use multiple lists but this approach allows me to understand the inner-workings of c#.
Is it efficient? Big-O maybe?

Comment: The convention for interface names is that they should start with `I`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does "typeof" include the types that are inherting clickable?

No, it doesn't. `ClickableEntity` and `Clickable` are two different types, so they are different keys in the dictionary.

Instead of a dictionary, you could just use a single `List<Entity>`, and filter it using `OfType`:

```
 protected List<Entity> entities;

 foreach (var c in entities.OfType<Clickable>())
 {
     ... Perform click
 }
```

Comment: As I thought... Would you suggest I just use multiple lists then?

Comment: @TFC, yes it would probably be best

Comment: I am currently using OfType, It just proved slow (Considering I am calling it on MouseMove), as such it would more efficient to create the a variable containing List<Clickable> clickables; on edit of the original list... as I said, efficiency is key, if I can do this without the uncessary "hardcoded" lists, it would be better

Comment: @TFC, in that case, yes, multiple lists are a better option. The only issue is that entities that implement multiple interfaces will have to appear in several lists.